# creating simple excel sheet in c# with strings as input

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I am working on creating EXcel sheet in C#.

```
No Of columns:4
Name of columns: SNO, Name, ID, Address
```

There is no constarint on number of rows.

```
         SNO   Name      ID   Address
          1     A         1122  XXXX
          2     B         2211  YYYY


         --- ---        ----    ---
```

I have strings as input

```
       string sno, string name, string Id, string address
```

I am actually new to C# background.

Can any one share their view on it like dlls needed etc.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you include a reference to [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can do whatever you please having Office installed on your system.

A little example:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_filename);
Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets.Add();
sh.Name = "TestSheet";
sh.Cells[1, "A"].Value2 = "SNO";
sh.Cells[2, "B"].Value2 = "A";
sh.Cells[2, "C"].Value2 = "1122";
wb.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```

Comment: I wanted to create an Exl file on a system on which Excel is not installed(MS Office not installed) , neverthless i want to create the xl file which i can transfer to another PC with MS office installed.Is it Still Possible?

Comment: @Raulp: you should use third party components because Excel Interop cannot work without Excel installed. You could also think about creating a CSV file instead...

Comment: @Raulp: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/1711103 discusses how to create excel spreadsheets without having excel installed.

Comment: SpreadSheetLight (.xlsx only) can be used to create without Excel installed along with most common operations http://spreadsheetlight.com/