# Unable to open excell sheet which created by c#

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I have created a excel sheet with the help of [creating simple excel sheet in c# with strings as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100901/creating-simple-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp-with-strings-as-input) link. It works fine the error when we open the saved excel sheet it shows message box like `"excel found unreadable content in "sample.xls". Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, Click Yes"`. May I know How it shows like this? My sample code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the data set and table
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("New_DataTable");

        //Set the locale for each
        ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        dt.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        //Create a query and fill the data table with the data from the DB

         SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand ("SELECT Name,EmpCode FROM EmpDetails where EmpCode='"+Neena102+"'",conn);
       // dr = conn.query(str);
        SqlDataAdapter adr = new SqlDataAdapter();

        adr.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adr.Fill(dt);
       //Add the table to the data set
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        var rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows;
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            string name=Convert.ToString(row["Name"]);
        //Here's the easy part. Create the Excel worksheet from the data set
        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(@"F:\\reports\\"+name+".xls", ds);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"F:\\reports\\" + name + ".xls");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use SQL Parameters to prevent from SQL injections.

Comment: @Sybren, If use SQL Parameters can I solve this issue??

Comment: No , but it's an important side node to prevent from SQL injections.

Comment: You will get the same message opening the file normally in Excel - your problem is within `ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook`.

Comment: How many rows are there in your dataset? I had a similar problem once that was "solved" by adding several empty rows so the filesize was over some limit.

Comment: @Hans Kesting, Just 2 rows

Comment: @NeenaJohn - then try and add some empty rows, maybe that fixes it

Comment: See also this issue and it's comments: https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=102

Comment: You can also consider using EPPlus instead - http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following changes.

Process startExcel = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"F:\reports\" + name + ".xls");
startExcel.WaitForExit();