# How to insert a single row data in a excel in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a method where i pass four parameters, like,

```
public void loggeneration(DateTime datetime, string projectname, int totallines,int sum,int max)
{
}
```

within the above method, i have to create a excel sheet(if file is present already, just append the data in the last blank row) and insert the data(datetime, projectname, totallines,sum,max) in a row of five columns.

The first row by default, should be the column names.

I have tried my best, could not find the exact solution. Can somebody provide the solution? Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is a good example here to get you started [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100901/creating-simple-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp-with-strings-as-input)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating simple excel sheet in c# with strings as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100901/creating-simple-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp-with-strings-as-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this question already exists in stack overflow. By the way you can try this simple solution.

```
  public void loggeneration(DateTime datetime, string projectname, int totallines, int sum, int max)
    {
        // this is the variable to your xls file 
        string path = @"c:\temp\log.xls";

        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                //once file was created insert the columns
                sw.WriteLine("date;projectname;totallines;sum;max");

            }
        }
        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", datetime, projectname, totallines, sum, max));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. The entire Data get entered in a single cell. Do you have any idea to insert the data into separate cells of the sheet

Comment: Hi, you are very welcome.
Sorry my mistake, use coma separated values extension instead of xls.
replace:

string path = @"c:\temp\log.xls";


for

string path = @"c:\temp\log.csv";

this may work

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the solution